# How to assign an input to a switch?

Tags: vhdl

I'm currently working on an 8-bit adder that instantiates a full adder. I have to assign 17 switches as inputs a , b and Cin. How can I do that?

Comment: How will you implement the design? ASIC, FPGA, PCB, ...?

Comment: Using an FPGA board - Altera DE 2

Comment: Then the switches are external to the VHDL design since they are part of the PCB, not part of the FPGA. The VHDL design just has inputs, which you assign to whichever pins of the FPGA are physically connected to the switches.

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to assign the inputs to a switch and the switch to LEDs? Do I have to maybe do a port mapping by creating another entity with the switch and the LEDs as I/O ports

Comment: No, you need to design your PCB to have LEDs and switches connected to the IO pins of your FPGA. Your VHDL doesn't know anything about switches and LEDs. It only knows what pins to connect its inputs and outputs to. (and actually that isn't even necessarily part of the VHDL, it's part of the constraints file, usually)

Comment: Feel free to write up your final solution as an answer so it can help future readers. That will also keep your question from re-appearing on the front page of the site.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Altera DE2 board, then you should use the Altera Quartus-II software. To change the pin assignments, follow these steps:

1. Write your VHDL code.
2. Change Flow to "Compilation" using the drop-down on the left side in the middle sub-window named "Tasks".
3. Double-click the step "Analysis & Synthesis". Check the log on the bottom for any errors and fix them.
4. Select menu "Assignments" --> "Pin Planner". In the new window, you will find the input and outputs of your design in a table. Edit the column "location" to connect an input/output to a specific pin of the FPGA. The required pin can be found in the documentation of the FPGA board.